# Reassigning position within an array

Tags: c++, arrays, function

I've been working on a dungeon crawling game, and I've hit an issue with moving the player's coordinates throughout my 2-d array. Currently, when choosing a move,  the move is passed into the function, but the position is not reassigned. I've tried both pass my reference and by value.

Currently as written, the program gets the players move, but I don't think it's actually being passed into the updateMove function. I tried having the function cout << playerMove, but it doesn't show anything. Am I doing something to cause the move to not be passed into the updateMove function? I'm guessing this is why the move isn't updating.

I've added my  main and the function in question:

`````
int main()
{
    // initialize random #
    srand(static_cast<int>(time(NULL)));

    do  // play again loop
    {
        // define variables
        bool win, lose;
        char playerMove;
        char dungeon[MAX_ROW][MAX_COL];
        int cash;

        displayInstructions(); // display instructions
        initializeDungeon(dungeon); // initialize dungeon

        do
        {
            setTraps(dungeon); // set traps
            displayDungeon(dungeon); // display dungeon
            playerMove = getMove(playerMove);

            // check for valid move
            // reassign player to new position
            updateMove(playerMove, dungeon);


            //update map now that move is legit
            if (!win && !lose)
            {
                updateDungeon();
            }

        } while (!win && !lose);

    } while (repeat());
}

void updateMove(char & playerMove, char dungeon[MAX_ROW][MAX_COL])
{
    int px, py;

    int dx = 0, dy = 0;
    if(playerMove == UP && px != 0)
    {
        dx--;
    }
    else if (playerMove == DOWN && px != 7)
    {
        dx++;
    }
    else if (playerMove == LEFT && py != 0)
    {
        dy--;
    }
    else if (playerMove == RIGHT && py != 8)
    {
        dy++;
    }

    if(dx != 0 || dy != 0)
    {
    dungeon[px][py] = SPACE; // I updated this to be an 'empty' space based on my variables
    px += dx;
    py += dy;
    dungeon[px][py] = PLAY;
    }
} ````
`````

Comment: And what is your question??

Comment: The position isn't being reassigned through this function. I'm wondering if I'm missing something? As far as I can tell the move is passed into the function but it seems to do nothing with it

Comment: You set the new position to PLAY (whatever that is) but you never change the old location of the '@'.

Comment: @MadisonFronabarger Please *edit your question* to add clarification. Don't just post a comment.

Comment: Divide and conquer. Back up your code and then hack your way down to a really small program that has the same misbehaviour. When you have a program that is nothing but the bug you're looking for, it's really easy to find the bug. You still might not know why it's a bug, but you found it and are in a really good position to ask well-targeted questions. Use [mcve] for inspiration.

Comment: Also you will need to change the down if statement to && row != 7 as the indices go from 0-7 for size 8

Comment: The issue is probably a pass by value vs pass by reference

Comment: Arrays are always pass by reference.

Answer (score 1):

Needing to iterate over the entire map to find the player is rather wasteful and slow. It also makes coding harder as you're seeing here.

You should store the player's position somewhere so you know it at a glance and can refer back to it for clearing the old position.

Something like this:

```
int px, py;

void updateMove(char playerMove, char dungeon[MAX_ROW][MAX_COL])
{
    int dx = 0, dy = 0;
    if(playerMove == 'u' && px != 0)
    {
        dx--;
    }
    else if (playerMove == 'd' && px != 8)
    {
        dx++;
    }
    else if (playerMove == 'l' && py != 0)
    {
        dy--;
    }
    else if (playerMove == 'r' && py != 9)
    {
        dy++;
    }

    if(dx != 0 || dy != 0) {
        dungeon[px][py] = EMPTY;
        px += dx;
        py += dy;
        dungeon[px][py] = PLAY;
    }
}
```

Comment: An improvement, but doesn't solve the problem the asker is struggling with.

Comment: It does remove the player's old location from the map @user4581301

Comment: Son of a gun. Missed that. Allow me to make a small edit to my comment. This might solve the problem now, but it's hard to be sure.

Comment: After trying your suggestion, I'm still having the same problem. So I'm guessing the issue is somewhere else in my program. Thank you so much for the improvement in efficiency of this function!

Comment: @MadisonFronabarger I think showing how you call `updateMove` might bring the issue to light. I suggest editing your question with the additional context.